# How do I make the loop go n times to find sum of nth terms? In C program

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, sequence

The question is:
Write a C program to determine the sum of the first Nth terms of the following series using loop {1+2+4+8....}

The code I've tried is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ 

  int i,sum=0,n;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for(i=1;i<n;i*=2)
    {
      sum=sum+i;
    }
  printf("Sum=%d\n",sum);  
    

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I enter N as 5 it gives an output of 7, but the output I am to expect is 31.

As, Sum of 5 terms is=1+2+4+8+16=31

So, I'm wondering how can I make my loop repeat 5 times or nth times, to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `i` is not increased by 1 each iteration but multiplied by 2. You need to add another variable to count the iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ 

  int i,value=1,sum=0,n;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      sum=sum+value;
      value *= 2;
    }
  printf("Sum=%d\n",sum);  
    

  return 0;
}
```

In addition, because 1+2+4+...+2^(n - 1) == 2^n - 1 (^ stands for power), you can calculate it with bitwise shifting without using loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){ 

  int sum,n;
  scanf("%d",&n);

  sum = (1 << n) - 1; // 1 << n equals to 2^n

  printf("Sum=%d\n",sum);  
    

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't update your variable which has been given the task of keeping track of the number of terms.

Since this question is related to the Geometric Progression, you can use its property to calculate the sum as well with it's

Sum of the series formula: a(r<sup>n</sup>-1)/(r-1), where a: First Term, r: common ratio

Also, add error checking for `scanf`.

Here is a code snippet for it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    int i, sum=0,n,value=1;
    if(scanf("%d", &n)!=1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Please input the valid number");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum +=value;
        value *=2;
    }
    
    printf("Sum=%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you use `sum` in 2 different contexts, your answer is wrong, and the loop will each iteration multiply `sum` by 3

Answer (score 0):

```
jot 15 |
```

> ```
> mawk '$++NF =-_ + ( $++NF =_+=_++ )' | column -t
> ```

```
1   1      1
2   2      3
3   4      7
4   8      15

5   16     31
6   32     63
7   64     127
8   128    255

9   256    511
10  512    1023
11  1024   2047
12  2048   4095

13  4096   8191
14  8192   16383
15  16384  32767
```

The 3 columns, left to right, represent :

> 1. **input** `N`
> 2. increment being added this round
> 3. summation **output**